# Error while calling webservice (Server was unable to process request. ---> PARAMETER_NAME)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, webservice-client

I get this error while calling the web service hosted on the server.
The service has one web method with as string input and returns string (will be in XML format). The service is working fine but once in a while I get this error and can't predict.  Can someone help me to get through this error.

Attached the screen shot of the error.  Please let me know if you need additional info

[image: error snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this error before, but I suggest you look at the event log on the server side. I suspect you are getting an unhandled exception on the client because you have one on the server.

Also, you should never return XML as a string. Use the XmlElement data type to return XML.